# How to give dynamic array to google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream?

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers

I have the following method that serialize my protocol buffer message and this works perfectly :

```
string DroolsMsgTransmission::serialize(const google::protobuf::Message* msg, const HeaderMsg& header)const
{
    unsigned char buffer[20000];

    google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream  arr(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream output(&arr);

    output.WriteVarint32(header.ByteSize());
    header.SerializeToCodedStream(&output);

    output.WriteVarint32(msg->ByteSize());
    msg->SerializeToCodedStream(&output);
    return string((char*)buffer, output.ByteCount());
}
```

Is it possible to use a dynamic buffer instead?  I tried the following:

```
string DroolsMsgTransmission::serialize(const google::protobuf::Message* msg, const HeaderMsg& header)const
{
    char* buffer = new char[header.ByteSize() + msg->ByteSize()]();

    google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream  arr(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream output(&arr);


    output.WriteVarint32(header.ByteSize());
    header.SerializeToCodedStream(&output);

    output.WriteVarint32(msg->ByteSize());
    msg->SerializeToCodedStream(&output);
    string str = string(buffer);
    delete buffer;
    return str;
}
```

But this is not working.  When I am trying the line above, the returned string does not contain the serialized data at all.

I also tried to use OstreamOutputStream instead of ArrayOutputStream, but no luck.

**EDIT**

Thanks to comments, I almost made it working :

```
string DroolsMsgTransmission::serialize(const google::protobuf::Message* msg, const HeaderMsg& header)const
{
    char* buffer = new char[header.ByteSize() + msg->ByteSize()]();

    google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream  arr(buffer, header.ByteSize() + msg->ByteSize());
    google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream output(&arr);


    output.WriteVarint32(header.ByteSize());
    header.SerializeToCodedStream(&output);

    output.WriteVarint32(msg->ByteSize());
    msg->SerializeToCodedStream(&output);
    string str = string(buffer ,output.ByteCount());
    //return string((char*)buffer, output.ByteCount());
    int toto = header.ByteSize() + msg->ByteSize();
    int tata = output.ByteCount();
    int titi = sizeof(buffer);
    delete buffer;
    return str;
}
```

What I did, I replaced this line

```
google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream  arr(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

by this line

```
google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream  arr(buffer, header.ByteSize() + msg->ByteSize());
```

I it better now, but I still have a problem where the returned string seems a little bit tuncated at the end.  It might be related with WriteVarint32, but I don't understand.  Somebody can explain why?

Thank you.

Comment: When you have `char* buffer;`, then `sizeof(buffer)` is not what the same as when you have `unsigned char buffer[20000];`.

Comment: Your first go looks nearly right - but you're not allowing for the size of the initial Varint32 that you're writing the header size as.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I am not sure to understand what you mean, but I posted an edit to show exactly what I tried to do.

Comment: Try printing `sizeof(buffer)` to see what it is.

Comment: @AlanStokes I make an edit to my post.  This is almost working, but the returned string is a little bit truncated.  I think you have the answer when you talked about the size of initial Varint32.  Could you provide more explanations, because I am not sure to understand?  THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing 4 things (the size of the header, the header, the size of the message, the message) but only allocating space for two of them (the header and message).

Hint: a Varint32 never takes more than 5 bytes.

(Also: you need the size in two places - when allocating the buffer and constructing `arr`. Compute it once and store it in a local variable.)